# creating resized thumbnail of image and video

Tags: java

I am trying to make resided
-  thumbnails of Images of any type. (thumb in .jpg though)
-  thumbnails of Video of its most middle frame.

I have seen some other stackoverflow questions and googled, but cant make any one working good.

e.g

used this code but it does not creates a good quality thumbnail.

```
package main;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;


import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Main implements Serializable {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {




                Main fac = new Main();
                fac.run("C:\\Users\\Masood-Ahmad\\Desktop\\tempSnaps");
    }        

            public void run(String folder) {
            File dir = new File(folder);
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                createThumbnail(file);
            }

         }

         private void createThumbnail(File file) {



                try {
                    // BufferedImage is the best (Toolkit images are less flexible)
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
                    BufferedImage thumb = createEmptyThumbnail();

                    // BufferedImage has a Graphics2D
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) thumb.getGraphics(); 
                   //**Edit-------------** 
                    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
                   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
                   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
                   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
                   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE);
                    //**Edit end----------------**
                    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 
                                  thumb.getWidth() - 1,
                                  thumb.getHeight() - 1, 
                                  0, 0, 
                                  img.getWidth() - 1,
                                  img.getHeight() - 1, 
                                  null);
                    g2d.dispose();
                    ImageIO.write(thumb, "JPG", createOutputFile(file));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private File createOutputFile(File inputFile) {
                // You'll want something better than this...
                return new File(inputFile.getAbsolutePath() 
                                + ".thumb.png");
            }

            private BufferedImage createEmptyThumbnail() {
                return new BufferedImage(200, 200, 
                                         BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use interpolation -- see `java.awt.RenderingHints` and `Graphics2D.setRenderingHint()`. This should help render a better-quality thumbnail.

There are some issues with using Java for generating thumbnails -- large graphics can consume large amounts of memory, some unusual images may be unreadable, and the supported formats are limited.

For wider image compatibility & format support, calling out to an external program such as Image Magick can offer better portability. See `Runtime.exec()` to do this.

Comment: I said interpolation! Use `RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION` and set it to `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC`, you've got every other possible hint set but not the actual one needed.

Comment: And I think your calls to `drawImage()` should use thumb and image width & height, not width-1 and height-1. Geometrical bounds are generally lower inclusive, upper exclusive so that their difference is the same as the number of pixels they measure.

Comment: Thanks, very nice, despite the RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION and set it to VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC made same results as before (or with no prominent change. I think think the thumb is small. 100 * 100 but still should give good results)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you Image Magick as it can produce good output.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the scaling each halving the resolution until you reach close to your targetresolution, then do the rest in one go